# Truth set of $\forall x \in A \exists y \in B P(x,y)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assuming $A= \{ x_0, \space x_1, \space x_2, ...\}$ and $B= \{ y_0, \space y_1, \space y_2, ...\}$, then $\forall x \in A \exists y \in B P(x,y)$ is logically equivalent to $[P(x_0,y_0) \lor P(x_0,y_1) \lor P(x_0,y_2)...] \wedge [P(x_1,y_0) \lor P(x_1,y_1) \lor P(x_1,y_2)...] \wedge ...$ (STATEMENT 1)

According to Vellemen in *How to prove it?*, $\forall x \in A \exists y \in B P(x,y)$ is the same as $\forall x[x \in A \rightarrow \exists y \in B P(x,y)]$.  If we expand this last formula, we get $[x_0 \in A \rightarrow (y_0 \in B)P(x_0, y_0) \lor (y_1 \in B)P(x_0, y_1) \lor (y_2 \in B)P(x_0, y_2)] \wedge [x_1 \in A \rightarrow (y_0 \in B)P(x_1, y_0) \lor (y_1 \in B)P(x_1, y_1) \lor (y_2 \in B)P(x_1, y_2)] \wedge ...$
(STATEMENT 2)

I can't' see how STATEMENT 1 and STATEMENT 2 are logically equivalent.

Comment: Try with 2 and 3 elements sets only...

Comment: The number of elements should not be an issue, if both statements are equivalent beforehand.

Comment: 2 is : "(if $x_0$ is in A then, either $P(x_0,y_0)$ holds or $P(x_0,y_1)$ holds or $P(x_0,y_2)$ holds) and (the same for $x_1$)"

Comment: But what is the meaning of the first conjunct ? It is "either $P(x_0,y_0)$ or $P(x_0,y_1)$ or $P(x_0,y_2)$"

Comment: That's exactly my point. To check wether $x_n$ is an element of A is not being considered in the first statement. As a consequence, the truth sets of both statements diverge.

Comment: @TylerD007 Membership in $A$ **is** considered in the first statement, because the only elements $x_n$ used there are exactly the elements of $A$.  Also, "the number of elements should not be an issue" for the mathematical content, but it is likely to be an issue for how easily you can understand the situation.

Comment: See [Restricted quantifier](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Restricted_quantifier): by def, $(\forall x \in A) Px$ means : $\forall x (x \in A \to Px)$ and similarly for the existential.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite statements are not part of First Order Logic.

Assume for all x in A, exists y in B with P(x,y).
Let x be any element.
If x in A, by the assumption, exists y in B with P(x,y).
Thus x in A implies exists y in B with P(x,y).
As x is any element,
. . for all x, (x in A implies exists y in B with P(x,y)).

Conversely assume
. . for all x, (x in A implies exists y in B with P(x,y)).
Let x be any element in A.
By the assumption, exists y in B with P(x,y).
As x is any element in A,
. . for all x in A, exists y in B with P(x,y).

Whereupon the two statements are equivalent.